# Only rotating mesh rendere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculusquest

I am pretty new in Unitym, and am working with the Oculus Quest 2, and have implemented a pokable object. I would like to have the object rotating around the x-axis, however not the whole game object, as I have a pointable plane fixated at the top of the object.

Is there any way to just rotate the material/mesh rendere?

Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity rotate around z axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716631/unity-rotate-around-z-axis)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I voted to close this question as it's been covered MANY times. Also, read the Unity API, it's really detailed with plenty of examples: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/